# Is it possible to view multiple burndown charts in tfs

Tags: tfs

I would like to know if is it possible to watch multiple burndown charts in one page.

We're using TFS and we have several projects in course. My boss wants to see in one page the burn downs of these projects, having a kind of dashboard. Do you know if tfs has something to do it?

Otherwise I will have to create a webpage and link them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing out of the box that lets you look at burndowns for a portfolio of team projects. You'll have to create the web page.